# pyton (RandomForestClassifier)

Tags: python, random-forest

How coplite code?
Create "RandomForestClassifier"

```
    r_forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 45,
    max_depth = 8,
    min_samples_leaf = 30,
    max_features = 30)
```

Create "AUC-ROC"

```
    r_forest_f = r_forest.fit
    y_pred_proba = r_forest_f.predict_proba (r_forest)[:,1]  //ERROR
    fpr, tpr, treshold = metrics. roc_curve (y_train, y_pred_proba)
    auc = metrics. roc_auc_score (y_train, y_pred_proba)
    plt.plot (fpr,tpr,label="name mofel= "+str(auc))
```

We need to build a schedule AUC-ROC, but it gives such an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-15f0a74b94a3> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 r_forest_f = r_forest.fit
----> 2 y_pred_proba = r_forest_f.predict(r_forest)[:,1]
      3 fpr, tpr, treshold = metrics. roc_curve (y_train, y_pred_proba)
      4 auc = metrics. roc_auc_score (y_train, y_pred_proba)
      5 plt.plot (fpr,tpr,label=" название модели= "+str(auc))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Comment: Your code and your error don't match ; `predict` vs `predict_proba`. You're also missing `()` after `fit`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error it produces. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from this line :

```
r_forest_f = r_forest.fit
```

You are assigning the `fit` method of the `RandomForestClassifier` to the `r_forest_f`. correct it :

```
r_forest_f = r_forest.fit(X, y)
```

Where `X` and `y` are your training data .

Check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) for more